# I am getting this Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Does anyone knows why?

Tags: c, malloc

Basically my project is for finding how many vowels and constants a string that I input has. But it doesn't work and I don't know why. I checked if the `malloc` works but it works find I guess.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define E_A_LETTERS 26

int check_vowels(char *p_string);

int main(void) {
    // Here your code !
    char *string;
    int vowels;
    int constants;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string);

    string = (char *)malloc(strlen(string) * sizeof(char));
    if (string == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory...");
        exit(0);
    }
    vowels = check_vowels(&string[0]);
    constants = E_A_LETTERS - vowels;

    printf("\nNumber of vowels : %d", vowels);
    printf("\nNumber of constants : %d\n", constants);
    free(string);
}

int check_vowels(char *p_string) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        if(*(p_string + i) == 65 || *(p_string + i) == 69 || *(p_string + i) == 73 || *(p_string + i) == 79 || *(p_string + i) == 85)
            count++;
        if(*(p_string + i) == 97 || *(p_string + i) == 101 || *(p_string + i) == 105 || *(p_string + i) == 111 || *(p_string + i) == 117)
            count ++;
        if(*(p_string + i) == '\0')
            break;
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Output Example - Error :

```
Enter a string: apples
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory *before* you use it, not *after* (the string pointer is invalid until you obtain it via `malloc`). So you need to decide what the maximum length of string you want to read (say it's MAX_LENGTH) and then do `string = malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char)+1);` (note the added 1 for trailing 0) and check for NULL *before* you call `gets(string)`.

Comment: @lurker Oh okay. Yea but whats the point of malloc if i cant allocate as much as the string is.

Comment: The point of `malloc` is to dynamically allocate the memory, regardless of how much it is. In a more complex program, you might find you can release it if you no longer need it. That's the point of `malloc`. But you can't predict in advance how long the string will be in order to precisely `malloc` that amount of memory. You need a specific number so you have the memory to read the string into. You can either use a maximum like I showed, or you can ask the user first how long their string would be (which is clunky).

Comment: Alternatively, you can read the string 1 char at a time and use `realloc` one byte at a time, but that would be very inefficient. If you have a simple program that just needs to read in a string, use it, then exit, there's really not much point in using `malloc`. Just declare, `char string[MAX_LENGTH+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `gets(string)` attempts to reads input into an invalid address as `string` is an uninitialized pointer. You should pass an array.
- `gets` is an obsolete function that cannot be used safely. You should use `fgets()` instead.
- the number of consonants is not `(26 - number_of_vowels)`. You should count the number of letters and subtract the number of vowels.
- it is much more readable and portable to use character constants such as `'A'` than actual ASCII codes like `65`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int count_vowels(const char *p_string);
int count_letters(const char *p_string);

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    int vowels;
    int constants;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("No input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    vowels = count_vowels(string);
    constants = count_letters(string) - vowels;

    printf("Number of vowels: %d\n", vowels);
    printf("Number of constants: %d\n", constants);

    return 0;
}

int count_vowels(const char *p) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (p[i] == 'A' || p[i] == 'E' || p[i] == 'I' || p[i] == 'O' || p[i] == 'U')
            count++;
        if (p[i] == 'a' || p[i] == 'e' || p[i] == 'i' || p[i] == 'o' || p[i] == 'u')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int count_letters(const char *p) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        /* assuming A-Z and a-z are contiguous, as is the case in ASCII */
        if ((p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z') || (p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z'))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: yea but that doesn't solve any of the problems above that i mentioned.

Comment: @AndreasSoteriou: what problem does it not solve? The segmentation fault should be fixed.